# PHP echo is Cutting off the Last String in Concatenation

Tags: php

My PHP code returns all of concatenated string except for the last string in the concatenation. How do I get the `'");</script>'` to echo as well?

PHP:

```
<?php
$server = mysqli_connect("111.111.111.111", "myname", "mypassword");

$query = "SELECT * FROM masks.maskPrimary";
$results = mysqli_query($server, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$echoer = '<script>let obj1 = new product("'.$row[2].'", "'.$row[3].'", "'.$row[4].'", "'.$row[5].'", "'.$row[1].'", "'.$row[6].'");</script>';

echo $echoer;
```

echo output:

```
<script>let obj1 = new product("Bigox Face Mask Disposable Earloop Blue 50Pcs", "$19.99", "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAwMDQsNCxAODBANEA4QExYRDRASGR8dFhsVHhgYEx4YFRsVFBwYGyAZHhsjKyQpIyA6LCYxGSYoRC5FOUsyLkIBCA4NDhITDhERExMREhYTJxsSES4cH", "paper", "amazon", "https://amazon.com/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A07729502ZDC3IUM61Q4B&url=%2FBigox-Face-Disposable-Earloop-50Pcs%2Fdp%2FB087RRWGJB%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fdchild%3D1%26keywords%3Dpaper%2Bmasks%26qid%3D1595873951%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1595873951&id=2851535447816864&widgetName=sp_atf
```

Comment: That should work. Make sure there isn't a quote mismatch, and double-check the response in the browser source. If you're using the Inspector console, it could try to guess if something isn't formatted right.

Comment: Are you actually saying the output is "value1" "value2" etc? Because I'm thinking you simplified what the actual output is here, and in fact its outputting data that is breaking the javascript itself (not escaping proper characters for JS). Have you inspected the HTML output of the php, and noted its actually 'cut off'? Because your code here, would not do that.

Comment: I did simplify it. I just updated it with the actual output.

Comment: That is the entirety of my PHP code.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw output in your network tab of the browser devtools? Are you saying its actually chopped off there, at that point, exactly as shown?

Comment: It seems to appear there, just not on the same line as the rest of it. This still gives this error in the console. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Sounds like a little bit of a dirty database. Must have a newline on the end of that column 6, which kills javascript. json_encode will take care of it, but its still 'dirty', and you may want to investigate how that got stored into the database in the first place. Using something like `trim()` around the outputs can clean those off on insert, and pulling.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'll take a look at the database to see where the root of the problem lays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` to put the values into the javascript. It will then take care of all the proper variable formatting for the javascript to handle. Change only this line to such:

```
$echoer = '<script>let obj1 = new product('. 
                                 json_encode($row[2]) .','.
                                 json_encode($row[3]) .','. 
                                 json_encode($row[4]) .','.
                                 json_encode($row[5]) .','.
                                 json_encode($row[1]) .','.
                                 json_encode($row[6]) .
          ');</script>';
```

It works well for this purpose. Even though JSON stands for OBJECT NOTATION, the PHP function works well with simple string output as well.

The alternative is to come up with a proper string escaper that makes all your row column outputs safe for javascript.